# Why when I use $(this) in a separate function and I call it inside a .each() it doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to make a clean jQuery code and I put all my things inside a function that I call in a "each". The problem is that nothing happens and in console doesn't appear any error.

That's an example code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.myElement').each(function() {
        if($(this).children()) {
            myFunction();
        } else {
            myFunction('.myOtherElement');
        }
    });
});

function myFunction(selector) {
    if(!selector) {
        $(this).html('Finish');
    } else {
        $(this).find(selector).html('Finish');
    }   
}
```

If I put my function content in .each it works, but in a separated function not, and I think that it should work. Why this snippet of code doesn't work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The execution context([this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)) is different in this case, you can use [.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to apply it

```
$(function() {
    $('.myElement').each(function() {
        if($(this).children()) {
            myFunction.call(this);
        } else {
            myFunction.call(this, '.myOtherElement');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `this` in your case is not your object inside `.each`, but is the `window` object. To bind the `this` as a jquery object ***without having to apply the context everytime you want it*** using `call` . You could define it as a jquery plugin function

```
(function($){
    $.fn.myFunction = function (selector) {
    if(!selector) {
        this.html('Finish'); //notice this here refer to jquery object instead of $(this)
    } else {
        this.find(selector).html('Finish');
    }   
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
    $('.myElement').each(function() {
        if($(this).children()) {
            $(this).myFunction();
        } else {
            $(this).myFunction('.myOtherElement');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: In that code I can use $(this) instead of this? Because I heard that $(this) is better for jQuery-like code.

Comment: @Flerex Ferwin: from jquery documentation, `this` is already a jquery object and don't need to use `$(this)`. As you're defining jquery plugin, anyone who reads the code should understand.

Comment: @Flerex Ferwin: I've not heard that $(this) is better for jQuery-like code, at least for jquery plugin